# import CSV File starting from a specific header value

Tags: powershell

I am trying to import a CSV file. It has some random data on top and I cannot skip the lines as I am not sure where the random data ends. There will be 2 empty lines and after that, there are headers and the desired data.

Lets say the random data looks like this 
"AD Group","USER ID","Property",
"NTDOMAIN\Doctors","sattar""Enabled"
"NTDOMAIN\Doctors","shayla""Disabled"
"NTDOMAIn\Nurses","mjane","Enabled"

"AD Group","GivenName", "ObjectClass","SURname","Name" ...morecolumns
"NTDOMAIN\Users","user1","user","User","1"
"NTDOMAIN\Users2","User1","User","User1_1","2"

How can I import the data that is under the headers (GivenName, SURname, Name). Also I just want to select some columns?

Comment: Do you know what the header line will look like for sure, or can you be confident that no lines before the header line will start with 'Name '?

Comment: This file will have multiple headers
1= A, B, C and under that it will have another set of header  2=Name, Phone, City and Name will always be a header

Comment: So, you'd need to detect data start as the "Name Phone..." header, and data end by the "A B C" header. And manually parse each line. Or, use a temp file, where you save filtered data (using data start/end detection by headers), and then import the temp file.

Comment: Your sample data is delimited by spaces, but your comment states a comma?

Comment: If I open the file in notepad, it shows the data like 
"A", "B", "C"
"w",  "DD",  "q"
"u", "o",   "p"
"A","Name" ,"Phone_Number", "City", "State"
"2","Nick", "800-524-8763", "NewYork" , "NY"
"0","Mike", "112-223-2222" ,"Richmond" , "VA"

The desired row has more columns but I wan to get only some columns. Also, I want to skip the first column from the selection as well.

Answer (score 2):

Provided the header line is fixed and can be used as a separator,
I'd use a RegEx with a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
$Header = "Name,Phone_Number,City"
$CsvData = (Get-Content '.\inputfile.csv' -raw) -Replace "(?s).*?(?=$Header)" | ConvertFrom-Csv
$CsvData
```

Sample output based on above data (assuming a **`comma`** separated file) :

```
Name Phone_Number City
---- ------------ ----
Nick 800-524-8763 NewYork
Mike 112-223-2222 Richmond
```

Answer (score 0):

```
## Read the file into an array, line-terminated
$f = [System.Io.File]::GetAllLines('path-to-csv')

## Stage the array to receive the filtered results
$clean = @()

## Loop through each entry in the file
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $f.count; $i++) {

   ## When the CSV header is found, filter the results and exit
   if ($f[$i] -eq "Name Phone_Number City") {
      $clean = $f[($i..($f.count - 1))]
      break
   }
}

## Turn the string array[] into and object that can be used in PowerShellese
$clean = $clean | convertfrom-csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is a pattern you can test with using `here strings` as input rather than a large file.  Very similar to answer from thepip3r.  Also, it appears your input is not using `Comma` as delimiter, so specified `Space`.

```
$csvtext = @"
A B  C
w DD q
u o  p
p u  o
Name Phone_Number City
Nick 800-524-8763 NewYork
Mike 112-223-2222 Richmond
"@

# replace with Get-Content of your file...
# $data = Get-Content ...
$data = $csvtext -split "`r`n"

$i = 0;
foreach($line in $data)
{
    if ($line.StartsWith("Name Phone_Number City")) { break; }
    $i++
}

$subdata = $data[$i..($data.Count-1)]

$csv = $subdata | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' '

$csv
```